# Not able to reference Operation contract method in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am creating a basic `Add 2 numbers` service in WCF. I have added the following inside `IService.cs`

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalc{
  [OperationContract]
  int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

Now, inside the `Service.cs` I have added

```
public class Service: IService, ICalc {
    public int Add(int a, int b){
       return a+b;
    }
}
```

Now I build this service and add a `service reference to it` inside a console application

```
Program.cs
```

It is called as

```
ICalService.Service c = new ICalService.Service();
int result = c.Add(10,20);        //Now on this line I cannot seem to get the Add(int a, int b) method
```

which I had declared earlier.

```
ICalService
```

is the name I gave to my service when it was referenced.

Why does the `Add(int a, int b)` method not show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a proxy for your IService interface or ICalc interface? From what it looks like you must have created a proxy for IService interface.

While adding web reference in the console application, ensure that you are creating a proxy (adding reference) to ICalcService interface.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a typo or missing from your question, but I don't see the interface IService actually defined, it is only implemented on your class 'Service'.  Also, it is sometimes helpful to simply browse to the .svc page you are trying to reference, the browser will sometimes show better error messages than what you would receive by trying to execute the action.

EDIT:
I would ensure that you're able to browse the .svc page and generate a WSDL.  If you're able to view the service operation and get a generated wsdl than I believe your service is up and running fine.  I would take others suggestion and ensure that you are then creating the proper proxy object.

Comment: IService was the predefined interface generated when I created the WCF service. I simply added the ICalc to it. I have tried rebuilding it many times, but even when the Add(int a, int b) gets referenced, it says agrument overload mismatch. I think I am definitely missing a step since it's my first time with WCF maybe